# Method configure(WebSecurity web) in Spring Security doesn't work

Tags: spring-security, web-config

I'm having a problem with Spring Security configuration, method configure(WebSecurity) isn't working properly, below is my source code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilter(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter())
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)  {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/auth", 
            "/v2/api-docs", 
            "/swagger-resources/**", 
            "/configuration/**", 
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/", "/refreshconfig", "/*.html", "/*.gif", "/favicon.ico", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.gif",
            "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js");
}


public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.class);

@Autowired
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    String token = request.getHeader(JwtTokenUtil.TOKEN_HEADER);
    Authentication authentication = null;

    try {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(token) && token.startsWith(JwtTokenUtil.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            log.info("JWT found {}", token);
            authentication = jwtTokenUtil.getAuthentication(token.replace(JwtTokenUtil.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        } else if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null
                && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()) {
            log.info("User already authenticated {}",
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        } else {
            log.info("Invalid JWT {}", token);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ON_RESOURCE);
        ErrorObj err = new ErrorObj(GamblingErrors.UNAUTHORIZED.getCode(), ex.getMessage());
        log.info("OUT ERROR END: {}", err.toString());
        response.getOutputStream().println(err.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException | MalformedJwtException | SignatureException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        ErrorObj err = new ErrorObj(GamblingErrors.UNAUTHORIZED.getCode(), ex.getMessage());
        log.info("OUT ERROR END: {}", err.toString());
        response.getOutputStream().println(err.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Even with the `configure(WebSecurity web)` method, still the filter added at `configure(HttpSecurity)` applies for all the resources, not taking in count the `web.ignoring`.
Can somebody give me an idea why it is not working?

Comment: Include in this post the source code for jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, please!

Comment: i added the source code for jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter

Comment: Is `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter`  annotated with @Service or @Component ?

Comment: no, its not annotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your source code, which is not complete in the question, i might suggest that **Spring Boot** is putting `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter` class automatically into the filter chain. So, although was correct to exclude */auth/* in the `ignoring()` method in security config, that wasn't enough to stop the filter from happening in the context of Spring Boot itself. The solution is to remove the annotation `@Bean` from `jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter()` method or to follow the other way explained in [Spring Security filter chain not ignoring specified path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716914/spring-security-filter-chain-not-ignoring-specified-path)